Why is clang compiler not found when building Darling on Ubuntu 20.04 WSL?
I'm trying to install Darling on Windows using Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL; Ubuntu 20.04) using these build instructions.
I get one error during the library installation step: E: Unable to locate package llvm-distutils. However, I found no mention of this library on the web, so I ignored it. Then I run through the instructions, and it all goes smoothly until the cmake .. step. I've copied the error message below. I also tried make after just in case, but error there too.
I've tried manually setting CMAKE_C_COMPILER and CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER as suggested in the error message and noted on the instructions, but I was not able to get it to recognize the absolute clang paths.
coppergenie@YEEHAW:~/darling$ cd build
coppergenie@YEEHAW:~/darling/build$ cmake ..
/home/coppergenie/darling/build/clang_major.c:3:2: error: #error "Not running on a clang compiler!"
    3 | #error "Not running on a clang compiler!"
      |  ^~~~~
/home/coppergenie/darling/build/clang_major.c: In function ‘main’:
/home/coppergenie/darling/build/clang_major.c:5:27: error: ‘__clang_major__’ undeclared (first use in this function)
    5 | int main() { printf("%d", __clang_major__); }
      |                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/coppergenie/darling/build/clang_major.c:5:27: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
CMake Error at cmake/clang_version_check.cmake:21 (message):
  Failed to build /home/coppergenie/darling/build/clang_major.c

  This could indicate that `/usr/bin/cc` is either not a clang compiler, or
  the path does not exist.  If you already have a supported version of clang
  installed, you may need to manually set CMAKE_C_COMPILER and
  CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER.  Refer to the Darling docs for more details.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:68 (clang_version_check)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/coppergenie/darling/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/coppergenie/darling/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
coppergenie@YEEHAW:~/darling/build$ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Any ideas?
Heads up that I have essentialy no experience whatsoever with Linux or macOS terminals and their commands. I'm just trying to follow instructions as best I can and look up the error messages; I don't really understand what clang or llvm or any of these things are for.
